# Is it faster to compare audio files with another audio file or process the file looking for specific word(s)?

Tags: android, audio

I was thinking of a side project that would use voice recognition for a music player on my phone. I haven't gotten through all the details but I was wondering would it be better to compare the audio file to another audio file that was  pre-recorded of the user saying the keyword or process the audio to look for a keyword?

Comment: apps like shazam already do this.

Comment: How do you think you're going to compare the files?

Answer (score 1):

comparison of the audio files would be faster